# implict SIMD (SSE/AVX) broadcasts with GCC

Tags: gcc, sse, simd, avx

I have manged to convert most of my SIMD code to us the vector extensions of GCC.  However, I have not found a good solution for doing a broadcast as follows

```
__m256 areg0 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(&a[i]);
```

I want to do

```
__m256 argeg0 = a[i];
```

If you see my answer at [Mutiplying vector by constant using SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273929/mutiplying-vector-by-constant-using-sse/20458599#20458599) I managed to get broadcasts working with another SIMD register.  The following works:

```
__m256 x,y;
y = x + 3.14159f; // broadcast x + 3.14159
y = 3.14159f*x;  // broadcast 3.14159*x
```

but this won't work:

```
 __m256 x;
 x = 3.14159f;  //should broadcast 3.14159 but does not work
```

How can I do this with GCC?

Comment: This appears to work fine in Clang using the OpenCL vector extentions `typedef float float4 __attribute__((ext_vector_type(8)));`.  However, Clang does not allow the broadcasts with a register using the GCC vector extensions so I'm not sure it is entirely compatible with GCC.

Comment: `__m256 zero={}; __m256 x=zero+3.14159f;`

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55726

Comment: @MarcGlisse, I tested your solution in GCC Explorer and I can confirm that it gets converted to vbroadcastss.  If you want to write up an answer I'll accept it.  I understand the ambiguity of double vs. float.  I guess it's even worse for integers since they can be 8-bits, 16-bits, 32-bits, or 64-bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is currently no direct way and you have to work around it using the syntax you already noticed:

```
__m256 zero={};
__m256 x=zero+3.14159f;
```

It may change in the future if we can agree on a good syntax, see [PR 55726](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55726).

Note that if you want to create a vector `{ s, s, ... s }` with a non-constant `float s`, the technique above only works with integers, or with floats and `-fno-signed-zeros`. You can tweak it to `__m256 x=s-zero;` and it will work unless you use `-frounding-math`. A last version, suggested by Z boson, is `__m256 x=(zero+1.f)*s;` which should work in most cases (except possibly with a compiler paranoid about sNaN).

Comment: This needs to be fixed. GCC cannot do this efficiently [due to signed zero](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43801280/2542702).  How hard is it to get involved with GCC development to fix something like this? I would like to help but I don't know if it's practical for me to try.

Comment: Actually, I just found an efficient solution.  `v4sf one = {1,1,1,1};
    x= one*3.14159f;`  This is because `x*1` can be simplified to just `x` for floating point.  See the end of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43801280/2542702).

Comment: So I could just have done `x = 3.14159f - (__m256){}`.  Apparently signed zero does not matter for `x-0`.

Comment: @Zboson as I wrote above, the x-0 version doesn't optimize with -frounding-math, so there are still cases where x*1 is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that with a precise floating point model (e.g. with `-O3`) that GCC [cannot simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272994/why-does-clang-optimize-away-x-1-0-but-not-x-0-0/33273367#33273367) `x+0` to `x` due to signed zero.  So `x = zero+3.14159f` produces inefficient code.  However GCC can simplify `1.0*x` to just `x` therefore the efficient solution in this case is.

```
__m256 x = ((__m256){} + 1)*3.14159f;
```

https://godbolt.org/g/5QAQkC

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43801280/2542702) for more details.

---

A simpler solution is just `x = 3.14159f - (__m256){}` because `x - 0 = x` irrespective of signed zero.