# GNU C native vectors: how to broadcast a scalar, like x86's _mm_set1_epi16

Tags: c, gcc, clang, simd, intrinsics

How do I write a portable [GNU C builtin vectors](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) version of this, which doesn't depend on the x86 set1 intrinsic?

```
typedef uint16_t v8su __attribute__((vector_size(16)));

v8su set1_u16_x86(uint16_t scalar) {
    return (v8su)_mm_set1_epi16(scalar);   // cast needed for gcc
}
```

Surely there must be a better way than

```
v8su set1_u16(uint16_t s) {
    return (v8su){s,s,s,s,  s,s,s,s};
}
```

I don't want to write an AVX2 version of that for broadcasting a single byte!

**Even a gcc-only or clang-only answer to this part would be interesting**, for cases where you want to assign to a variable instead of only using as an operand to a binary operator (which works well with gcc, see below).

---

If I want to use a broadcast-scalar as one operand of a binary operator, this works with gcc ([as documented in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)), but not with clang:

```
v8su vecdiv10(v8su v) { return v / 10; }   // doesn't compile with clang
```

With clang, if I'm targeting only x86 and just using native vector syntax [to get the compiler to generate modular multiplicative inverse constants and instructions for me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323845/whats-the-fastest-way-to-generate-a-1-gb-text-file-containing-random-digits/324520#324520), I can write:

```
v8su vecdiv_set1(v8su v) {
    return v / (v8su)_mm_set1_epi16(10);   // gcc needs the cast
}
```

But then I have to change the intrinsic if I widen the vector (to `_mm256_set1_epi16`), instead of converting the whole code to AVX2 by changing to `vector_size(32)` in one place (for pure-vertical SIMD that doesn't need shuffling).  It also defeats part of the purpose of native vectors, since that won't compile for ARM or any non-x86 target.

The ugly cast is required because gcc, unlike clang, doesn't consider `v8us {aka __vector(8) short unsigned int}` compatible with `__m128i {aka __vector(2) long long int}`.

BTW, all of this compiles to good asm with gcc and clang ([see it on Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Atypedef+uint16_t+v8su+__attribute__((vector_size(16)))%3B%0A%0Av8su+set1_u16(uint16_t+s)+%7B%0A++return+(v8su)%7Bs,s,s,s,++s,s,s,s%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Av8su+set1_u16_x86(uint16_t+scalar)+%7B%0A++return+(v8su)_mm_set1_epi16(scalar)%3B+++//+cast+needed+for+gcc%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23if+!!defined(__clang__)+%26%26+!!defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)%0Av8su+vecdiv_scalar(v8su+v)+%7B+return+v+/+10%3B+%7D%0A%23endif%0A%0Av8su+vecdiv_set1(v8su+v)+%7B%0A++return+v+/+(v8su)_mm_set1_epi16(10)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang390,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+3.9.0',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).  **This is just a question of how to write elegantly, with readable syntax that doesn't repeat the scalar N times**.  e.g. `v / 10` is compact enough that there's no need to even put it in its own function.

Compiling efficiently with ICC is a bonus, but not required.  GNU C native vectors are clearly an afterthought for ICC, and even [simple stuff like this doesn't compile efficiently](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Atypedef+uint16_t+v8su+__attribute__((vector_size(16)))%3B%0A%0Av8su+set1_u16(uint16_t+s)+%7B%0A++return+(v8su)%7Bs,s,s,s,++s,s,s,s%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Av8su+set1_u16_x86(uint16_t+scalar)+%7B%0A++return+(v8su)_mm_set1_epi16(scalar)%3B+++//+cast+needed+for+gcc%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23if+!!defined(__clang__)+%26%26+!!defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)%0Av8su+vecdiv_scalar(v8su+v)+%7B+return+v+/+10%3B+%7D%0A%23endif%0A%0Av8su+vecdiv_set1(v8su+v)+%7B%0A++return+v+/+(v8su)_mm_set1_epi16(10)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc17,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-O3+-xHOST+-march%3Dhaswell+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+icc+17',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-xc+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  `set1_u16` compiles to 8 scalar stores and a vector load, instead of MOVD / VPBROADCASTW (with `-xHOST` enabled, because it doesn't recognize `-march=haswell`, but Godbolt runs on a server with AVX2 support).  Purely casting the results of `_mm_` intrinsics is ok, but the division calls an SVML function!

Comment: You can't reasonably use gcc vector intrinsics in clang *anyway*, since they oh-so-wisely decided to implement totally different `__bultin_shuffle()` semantics.

Comment: I just found some old code I wrote where I worked around the missing gcc vector intrinsic broadcast by doing `vectype v = {0}; v += scalartype;`. gcc optimizes this to a broadcast. It's not pretty (because it can't be `const`), but it's fairly short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic broadcast solution can be found for GCC and Clang using two observations

1. [Clang's OpenCL vector extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors) and GCC's vector extensions support `scalar - vector` operations.
2. `x - 0 = x` ([but `x + 0` does not work due to signed zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273367/2542702)).

Here is a solution for a vector of four floats.

```
#if defined (__clang__)
typedef float v4sf __attribute__((ext_vector_type(4)));
#else
typedef float v4sf __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
#endif

v4sf broadcast4f(float x) {
  return x - (v4sf){};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/PXr3Xb

The same generic solution can be used for different vectors. Here is an example for a vector of eight unsigned shorts.

```
#if defined (__clang__)
typedef unsigned short v8su __attribute__((ext_vector_type(8)));
#else
typedef unsigned short v8su __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
#endif

v8su broadcast8us(short x) {
  return x - (v8su){};
}
```

ICC (17) supports a subset of the GCC vector extensions but does not support either `vector + scalar` or `vector*scalar` yet so intrinsics are still necessary for broadcasts. MSVC does not support any vector 
extensions.

Comment: Adding to zero can work well for integer, but not for float without `-ffast-math`.  Signed-zero behaviour (and possibly raising exceptions) means`x + 0.0` can't be optimized to `x`, so the non-clang ifdef branch (`zero + x`) doesn't optimize away: [gcc has a `vaddss` from a scalar constant before the shuffle](https://godbolt.org/g/US7TSZ).

Comment: Upvoted because this answer works for clang (avoids adding to zero), but I don't think I'm ready to accept this answer.  (AFAIK, there *isn't* an answer other than manually typing out the same variable up to 8 times in an initializer, for v8sf.  Presumably integer types will still optimize `0 + x` to `x` (like EOF mentions in a comment), so we can use this for integer vectors and avoid typing it out 32 times for v32sc).

Comment: @PeterCordes, I just fixed it for GCC! Instead of doing `zero + x` you can do `one*x`! https://godbolt.org/g/1a39Kv. See my updated answer.

Comment: Nice, that's exactly the kind of trick that answers this question.  You should make that version the first version in your answer, since there's no downside.  You can initialize `one` without typing out a comma-separate list of ones by doing `v4sf one = ((v4sf){}) + 1.0;`.  0.0 + 1.0 does optimize away at compile time because both operands are constants.  https://godbolt.org/g/Xek2hV.  This can get rid of gcc vs. clang `#ifdef`s other than in the `typedef`, but it seems ICC still needs custom `_mm_set1_...` intrinsics.

Comment: So I think you could make a generic broadcast macro or template for gcc/clang (which accepts a typename and a scalar, and returns the scalar broadcast to a 16-byte vector), but not for ICC.

Comment: I made a nice table at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43778723/2542702) that may interest you.

Comment: @PeterCordes. A simpler solution `x - (v4sf){}`. https://godbolt.org/g/2NHhAo . See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21732581/2542702). Apparently `x - 0` is okay as well. It's just `x + 0` that is the problem. https://godbolt.org/g/nXfIoH

Comment: @PeterCordes apparently `((v4sf){} + 1)*x;` may still be useful if `-frounding-math` is used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727331/implict-simd-sse-avx-broadcasts-with-gcc/21732581?noredirect=1#comment74815992_21732581